# Passing the context to the watson conversation

Tags: watson-conversation

Needing help for passing the context to the Watson conversation at any point in the conversation, without influencing the flow.
it's possible?

Example: 
API integration fetches the data and set to the conversation context. Two dialog boxes after I am use the context variable.

Thanks very much

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for, but you can pass in user-defined context any time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik. 
I needed to pass parameters to the context outside the moment of the conversation; But it is not possible. The alternative was to create an empty node that accepts the user input and a jump to the next node with the conversation continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Like @data_henrik said you can pass the context anytime. To take the user input:

```
{
"context":{
"time":"@sys-time"
},
```

To use it anywhere use the symbol $. Ex:

```
condition: if bot recognize $time
Then respond with: The time is @sys-time.
```

Comment: Thanks @barbs. 
I needed to pass parameters to the context outside the moment of the conversation; But it is not possible. The alternative was to create an empty node that accepts the user input and a jump to the next node with the conversation continuing.